# C++ request for member in , which is of non-class type

Tags: c++

I'm probably ignoring some detail, but why can't I call the write method on the object `a`?

The error is

> request for member 'write' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'CFile()

https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3xz85x4ra

```
class CFile
{
    public:
        CFile(void); // copy cons, dtor, op=
        ~CFile (void);
        uint32_t write ( const uint8_t *src, uint32_t bytes );
        
        uint8_t *m_Data;
        uint32_t m_Len;
        uint32_t m_Position;
        uint32_t m_Capacity;
    private:

};

CFile::CFile(void)
:m_Data(nullptr), m_Len(0), m_Position(0), m_Capacity(0)
{
}

CFile::~CFile (void)
{
    delete[] m_Data;
}


uint32_t CFile::write ( const uint8_t *src, uint32_t bytes )
{
    ...
}


int main (void)
{
    uint8_t point[]={1,2,3};
    CFile a();
    
    a.write(point, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CFile a();` is declaration of a function named `a` that takes no arguments and returns a `CFile`. Use `{}` instead of `()` to avoid that.

Comment: When asking questions about build errors (or warning), then besides showing us the actual [mre] causing the error, also please copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete build output into the question itself.

Comment: Perhaps it might also be a good time to refresh  [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).